# Configure Entity Framework to read and write entity property of type List<string>

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is it possible to configure mapping (some kind of converter?) of below entity in EF7

```
public class Car
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<string> Options {get;set;}
}
```

where options is `nvarchar(max)` column separated by `;`, for example

```
radio;tv;abs
```

Comment: That would break the whole relational database model EF is trying to achieve. Technically you could bastardize the model to make this behavior work.... but why would you want to do this?

Comment: I use http://docs.servicestack.net/text-serializers/json-csv-jsv-serializers and some columns contains serialized data. I wish my entities were compatible with ServiceStack.OrmLite and EF7

Comment: So the goal is to automatically deserialise a json response which contains arrays of data back into an entity model?